# passing a struct to a function doesnt work

Tags: c, function, struct, return

In the below code I have create a function apart from main to divided the int inside a struct into half.

After that, I want to print out the new value. However, the print out value is still the old one.

I believe my fundamental knowledge of struct and pointers are not good enough.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks a lot!!!

```
typedef struct{
    int age;
    int wage;
}person;


void divide(person A)
{
    person half;
    half.age = A.age / 2;
    half.wage = A.wage / 2;
    
    A = half;
}

int main(void)
{
    person A;
    A.age = 30;
    A.wage = 35000;
    
    divide(A);
    
    printf("%i\n", A.age);

}
```

Comment: Add a tag for the programming language you are using.

Comment: The `A` in `main()` and the `A` in `divide()` are different objects with the same (local) identifier. Changes you make to the `A` in `divide()` are not reflected in the `A` in `main()`. Maybe try returning the changed `A` from `divide()`? `person divide(person A) { /*...*/ return A; }` or pass a pointer instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. Got a little glimpse now, if I want to do the pointer method, how do I start? I am a little confused about pointers to a struct.

Comment: for pointer: `void divide(person *A) { A->age /= 2; A->wage /= 2; }` and `divide(&A);` in `main()`. BTW `A->age` is the same as `(*A).age`

Comment: How would you imagine this would work? Say it was `void divide(int a) { int half = a/2; a = half; }` and then you did `divide(4);`, how do you think the 2 would get back to the caller? If it won't work for `int`, it won't work for a `struct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `divide` is modifying a copy of that structure since structures are pass by value. You will need to pass the pointer to the structure, so the function can modify the original.

```
void divide(person* A)
{
    person half;

    half.age  = A->age  / 2;
    half.wage = A->wage / 2;
    
    *A = half;
}
```

Called `divide` with address of original structure

```
divide(&A);
```

Comment: @Fredrik: that's not true at all, it doesn't matter that `half` goes out of scope because it's value is assigned to `*A` before it does. This answer is just as valid as mine.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass `A` to `divide`, a copy of `A` is created. Modifying this copy inside `divide` has no effect on the local variable `A` you defined  in `main`. To remedy this, you can make `divide` take a *pointer* to `person`. A pointer effectively represents an address in memory such that you can use it to e.g. access local variables defined in other functions that would otherwise not be accessible (research *stack frames* if you want to understand why this is).

So in practice you change `divide`'s signature to: `void divide(person *A)` and in the last line of this function you assing not to `A` but to whatever `A` is pointing to by using the dereference operator: `*A = half`. In your `main` function you then pass the *address* of `A` instead of `A` itself to `divide` using the address of operator: `divide(&A)`.

EDIT: even better, you can avoid creating the temporary `half` by directly performing: `A->age /= 2` and `A->wage /= 2` where `A.x` is syntactic sugar for `(*A).x`.